# Redirect arrow keys from TextBox to ListBox

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox with a ListView underneath, and I'd like to redirect the up and down arrow keys to the ListView, when the TextBox has the focus. Before I do anything ad-hoc, does someone know a way to redirect keys between controls?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you could set KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation.aspx), but I think due to the way that textboxes handle directional keys, that this would get ignored.

As an alternative, you could handle PreviewKeyDown to make the up and down arrow simulate tabbing.

```
    <StackPanel PreviewKeyDown="StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown"  >
        <TextBox Text="Test" TabIndex="0" />
        <ListView TabIndex="1">
            <ListViewItem>One</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Two</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Three</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

    private void StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up:

                ((UIElement)Keyboard.FocusedElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
                e.Handled = true;

                break;
            case Key.Down:
                ((UIElement)Keyboard.FocusedElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                e.Handled = true;

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand this code correctly, all it does is make Up and Down behave like Tab and Shift+Tab? The point is to move to the next and previous item in the `ListBox` while the cursor still blinks in the `TextBox`. I hoped to do this by key redirection, but I guess I'll use `PreviewKeyDown` and manually change the selected item.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood on the original intent.  PreviewKeyDown still probably seems like the event to consume and then increment/decrement the ListBox.SelectedIndex appropriately.