# Can't We get Current value of Text Box in PreviewKeyDown Event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to read Current value of Text Box in  **PreviewKeyDown** Event but unable to get current value.

Here is my code ,

```
    private void txtDoscountValue_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          if  (txtDoscountValue.Text == string.Empty)
              discountPercentage = 0;
          else
              discountPercentage = float.Parse(txtDoscountValue.Text);
              CalculateCart(cartItems, discountPercentage, 0);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you are asking at `PreviewKeyDown`, so when it gets called, there is still no values in the box. If you want to get called when the box actually changes you need to hook to `KeyDown` or even better `TextChanged`.

`PreviewKeyDown` is for checking the content of the change before actually applying it, which is kind of validation.

The value of the modification is stored in the `keyEventArgs`, not in the textbox.

Comment: your right @javirs. But As per my scenario I am trying to implement logic in PreviewKeydown event . So its not possible getting current value in PreviewkeyDown Event right???

Comment: Yo do get the OLD value in the object.Text variable PLUS the modifications in the keyEventArgs.keyValue. On first click the OLD value is  empty. you can validate or cancel the edit of the user by setting the e.Handled to true or false

Comment: Why KeyDown Event is not firing for UP,DOWN,LEFT AND RIGHT arrows

Comment: acording to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938182/redirect-arrow-keys-from-textbox-to-listbox   it does catch arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read value of **TextBox** at any time with `Text` property of `TextBox` control:

```
var currentValue=textBox.Text;
```

To read inputted `keys` of keyboard, you can use `e.Key` of `KeyEventArgs`:

```
private void txtDoscountValue_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     string input=e.Key;                
     var ee = txtDoscountValue.Text;               
  }
  catch { }
}
```

**Update:**

It is possible to use `KeyConverter` class to convert `Keys` to string. You should add reference to assembly **System.Windows.Forms** to your WPF project to use `KeyConverter` class:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender,  System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {               
     char c = '\0';
     System.Windows.Input.Key key = e.Key;
     if ((key >= Key.A) && (key <= Key.Z))
     {
       c = (char)((int)'a' + (int)(key - Key.A));
     }
     else if ((key >= Key.D0) && (key <= Key.D9))
     {
       c = (char)((int)'0' + (int)(key - Key.D0));
     }
     else if ((key >= Key.NumPad0) && (key <= Key.NumPad9))
     {
       c = (char)((int)'0' + (int)(key - Key.NumPad0));
     }
     //here your logic
  }
  catch { }     
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your Reply  @stepUp but I Know that. I am asking in PreviewKeyDown Event

Comment: As per my situation TextChanged is not suitable for me and I have checked your suggestions but I am getting key names like "Back","D2","NumPad8" in EventArgs object ...

Comment: No. Actually I want to perform some calculations based on text box value and one more thing is this Text Box value is changing in some other place at a same time that's why i am not using TextChanged Event

Comment: Sorry @StepUp its not working properly ... for example  when i am entered 8 from num keypad i am getting value as  "NumPad8" but I want only entered value

Comment: @sagar please see my updated answer. I've edited approach. Hope it helps, feel free to ask any question:).

Comment: @ StepUp Sorry ... its not working for me ...any how I have changed my logic and implemented in TextChanged Event Only ... Thank you so much for your valuable suggestions .